# How to integrate migs api in C# with vcp_CardNum and vpc_CardSecurityCode and SHA256 Secure Hash Type

Tags: c#, mastercard

Migs Integration with C# including card details with SHA256 hash

Answer (score 1):

The following is a working code taken from [proj solution](http://www.projsolution.com/a103-41977-c%23)

```
var secureSecret = "123456789ABCDEF123456789ABCDEF12";
        var args = new SortedDictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"vpc_Version", "1"},
            {"vpc_Command", "refund"},
            {"vpc_MerchTxnRef", "TestRefund"},
            {"vpc_AccessCode", "XXXXXXXX"},
            {"vpc_Merchant", "XXXXXXXX"},
            {"vpc_TransNo", "123"},
            {"vpc_Amount", "1"}
        };
        var getPart = "";
        foreach (var arg in args)
        {
            getPart += arg.Key + "=" + arg.Value + "&";
        }
        getPart = getPart.TrimEnd('&');
        var keyBytes = new byte[secureSecret.Length / 2];
        for(int i=0;i<keyBytes.Length;i++)
        {
            keyBytes[i] = byte.Parse(secureSecret.Substring(i * 2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        }
        var hmac = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes);
        var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(getPart));
        var hashString = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "");
        var requestUri = "https://migs.mastercard.com.au/vpcpay?"+getPart+"&vpc_SecureHash="+hashString+"&vpc_SecureHashType=SHA256";
```